# My form does not save using bootstrap for styling in django

Tags: django, forms, styling, django-bootstrap4

hello thank you for your visiting
I'm a new learner of Django
I would like to know how to style  form using django-bootstrap-v5
i try this and does not work

i have this form.py

```
pathesForm = inlineformset_factory(
    Book,
     quotation,
      fields=('name','time',),
      can_delete=False,extra=4,max_num=4,
      widgets={'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'name of book',
        })
    }
    
      )
```

i use  django-bootstrap-v5  and in file html

this form  is not  working with me

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
      {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
          <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          {%  bootstrap_field form.name %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          {%  bootstrap_field form.time %}
        </div>
      </div>
      {%  if form.maybemissing %}
        {%  bootstrap_field form.maybemissing %}
      {%  endif %}
{% endfor %}

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

but this is working with me (i can save the form)

```
{% bootstrap_formset_errors formset %}
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    
          {%  bootstrap_formset formset %}
      
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

this is my view.py

```
def hello(request,id):
    book=Book.objects.get(id=id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form= pathesForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=book)
            if form.is_valid():

                form.save()
        
            
        form = pathesForm(instance=book )
        

        return render(request,'hello/pathesForm.html',{'formset':form})
```

i use print('hello) to try know where is the problem and the result seems like the form is not valid
how i can to customize  the style of my form like the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allways if you have a problem with from use print(form.errors) before the form is valid and after it
i got my problem and i got this error [{'id': ['This field is required.']}
soulition:

```
    <form role="form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
      {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
          {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
          <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          {%  bootstrap_field form.name %}
        </div>
      </div>
      {%  if form.maybemissing %}
        {%  bootstrap_field form.maybemissing %}
      {%  endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

i think it success using formset only because of ( id add automatically )
and if you want to forloop you should be add it manually

Answer (score 0):

in your views you forgot to pass then else statement so here it is

```
def hello(request,id):
    book=Book.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= pathesForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=book)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()    
    else:   
        form = pathesForm(instance=book)
        return render(request,'hello/pathesForm.html',{'formset':form})
```

and in your html while requsting the file field
you have to give form a encryptio type here it is

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

this has to solve your problem and tell me if you still getting any error have a good day

Comment: the problem is not how to style form with bootstrap

Comment: the problem why the form dose not save

Comment: then please be more precise while asking the question and use the right title anways updating my anwser

Comment: else statement do not anything  and the enctype don't success

Comment: anyway i got the problem i will to post the right answer

Comment: so what wrong in my anwser i didn't get it

Comment: as i can see u are requesting file in your form then you must use enctype othwewise your form will not save

Comment: and if not requesting any file remvoe request.FILES from you views because it doesn't make sense